# Not able to place two divs in single row in responsive design

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I have a web page which has been designed to suit mobile and web. I have a footer in that page and that footer is made up of 4 columns (each having 25% width). And when the mobile mode is triggered i had made it such that the width of each column is made to 50% so that the footer gets split into two rows (each row having two columns). To achieve this I had given the columns a two-class name. And in one of the classes under the media in CSS I specified it to take only 50% width in the mobile view. However, even though the CSS gets reflected for each of the columns kin mobile view it still takes up 100% of the width and produces 4 rows with each rowing having one of the columns. I have attached the screenshots along with the code. Can anyone point me out where am wrong?

[image: Footer in web with 4 columns in one row]

[image: Footer in mobility view with one column in each row]

[image: CSS shows 50% width command is applied]

```css
/********DEFAULTS*******/
nav,header,footer
{
    display:block;
}

body
{
    line-height: 1;
    margin :0;
}

label
{
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 600
}

p
{
    font-size:28px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

article p
{
    font-size:35px;
    padding:20px;
}

/********NAV BAR*******/
nav
{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}

nav ul
{
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.topnav li
{
    list-style: none;
    float : left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.topnav li.topnav-right
{
    float : right;
}

ul.topnav li a
{
    display : block;
    text-decoration : none;
    min-height:16px;
    text-align:centre;
    padding:14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#665;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover
{
    background-color: #0000ff;
    color:#fff;
}

ul.topnav li.dropdownicon
{
    display: none;
}
button
{
    font-size:32px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#0069ff;
    padding: 15px 60px;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    margin:5px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

button.learnMore
{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
.container 
{
    width : 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 4%;
    padding-bottom: 4%;   
    background: 
}
/********custom style*******/
#section-1-gradient
{
    background:#076DFF;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#076DFF, #65A5FF);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#076DFF, #65A5FF);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#076DFF, #65A5FF);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#076DFF, #65A5FF);
}

div.box
{
    margin:24px;
    text-align:center;  
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 36px 24px 36px 24px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.15),
        0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

div.slopeIcon img
{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    box-shadow: -2px -2px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15),
        2px 2px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
h1.large
{
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 56px;
    margin:0;
    line-height: 70px;
}

h1.section2header
{
    font-size:65px;
    text-align:center;
}

div.leftside-col
{
    margin-left:30%;
    
}

div.rightside-col
{
    margin-left:15%;    
}
input[type="password"], /* added by shamil*/
input[type="text"]
{
    font-size: 20px;
    width:400px;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius: 7px
}



form h2
{
    color:white;
}
.row
{
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex:wrap;    
    align-items:center;    
}

.row::after
{
    display:table;
    clear: both;
    content:"";
}

.col-1{width:8.33%;}
.col-2{width:16.66%;}
.col-3{width:25%;}
.col-4{width:33.33%;}
.col-5{width:41.66%;}
.col-6{width:50%;}
.col-7{width:58.33%;}
.col-8{width:66.66%;}
.col-9{width:75%;}
.col-10{width:83.33%;}
.col-11{width:91.66%;}
.col-12{width:100%;}


*{
    box-sizing: border-box
}

footer.footsy
{
    background-color: #666; 
    padding:2%
}

footer.footsy h1
{
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 35px;
}

footer.footsy ul
{
    list-style: none;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left: 0;
}

footer.footsy ul li
{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:22px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
/********MOBILE*******/
@media screen and (max-width : 680px)
{
    ul.topnav li:not(:nth-child(1))
    {
        display: none;
    }
    ul.topnav li.dropdownicon
    {
        display:block;
        float: right;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li.dropdownicon{
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive{
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li{
        display:inline;
        float : none;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li a
    {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    h1.section2header
    {
        font-size:55px;
    }
    
    .row {
    flex-direction: column;
        
    }
    
    article p
    {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    
    .col-4,
    .col-5,
    .col-6,
    .col-7
    {
        width:100%;
        margin:0;            
    }
    
    div.mobilestack
    {
        width:50%;
        display:block;
        margin:0;
    }
    
    div.box
    {
        padding:5px;
        display:block;
    }
    div.slopeIcon
    {
        margin:10px;
    }
    div.slopeIcon img
    {
        width:100%;
    }
    
    div.rightside-col,
    div.leftside-col
    {
        width:15%;
    }
   input[type="password"],
    input[type="text"]
    {
        width:200px;
        float:left;
        padding:5px;
    }
   .videoContainer iframe
    {
       width:400px;
        float:left;
        padding:5px; ;
    }
}
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>
        Anime Shop 
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">              

    </head>
    
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul class="topnav" id="dropdownClick">
                <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#News">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
                <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#Signup">Sign up</a></li>
                <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#Signin">Sign in</a></li>
                <li class="dropdownicon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick = "dropdownMenu()">&#9776</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <div class="container" id="section-1-gradient">
            <div class="row">
                <div class= "col-6">
                    <div class= "leftside-col">
                        <h1 class="large">
                        Crazy radness
                        </h1>
                        <h1 class="large">
                        Made for Otaku
                        </h1>
                        <form>
                            <div class= "leftside-col">
                                <h2>Username</h2>
                                <input class="inputbox" type="text" name="Username "placeholder="Username">
                                <h2>Password</h2>
                                <input class="inputbox" type="password" name="Password "placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class= "col-6">
                    <div class= "rightside-col">
                        <div class="videoContainer">
                            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uC_SgMzlr6U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>     
        </div>
        <header>
        <h1 class = "section2header"> Top Anime Counties </h1>  
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img src="devIcon.png">
                        </div>
                        <label>Anime</label>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
                    </div>              
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img src="devIcon.png">
                        </div>
                        <label>Manga</label>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
                    </div>              
                </div>  
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img src="devIcon.png">
                        </div>
                        <label>Anime and Manga</label>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
                    </div>              
                </div>  
                
            </div>                      
            <div class ="row">
                    <div class ="col-12">
                        <button class="learnMore">Learn More</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7">
                    <article>
                        <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                        </p>
                    </article>

                </div>
                <div class= "col-5">
                    <div class="slopeIcon">
                        <img src="iOS_Slope.png">
                    </div>          
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
         <footer class="footsy">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3 mobilestack">
                    <h1>Company</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Blogs</li>
                        <li>Careers</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 mobilestack">
                    <h1>Organization</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Blogs</li>
                        <li>Careers</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 mobilestack">
                    <h1>Industry</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Blogs</li>
                        <li>Careers</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 mobilestack">
                    <h1>Maanagement</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Blogs</li>
                        <li>Careers</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </footer> 
        <script>
            function dropdownMenu()           
            {
               var x= document.getElementById("dropdownClick");
                if(x.className === "topnav")
                {
                    x.className = "topnav responsive";
                    /*change topnav to topnav.responsive*/
                }
                else
                {
                    x.className = "topnav";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: With display: block; the element take always all of the space (100%). If you want the element take onlny 50% change the display property in inline-block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.row` element in your footer has `flex-direction: column;`, which is the reason for your problem - that way its children will always be stacked vertically, regardless of their width.

To change that, add the following CSS rule inside your media query for mobile:

```
.footsy .row {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```css
/********DEFAULTS*******/
nav,header,footer
{
    display:block;
}

body
{
    line-height: 1;
    margin :0;
}

label
{
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 600
}

p
{
    font-size:28px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

article p
{
    font-size:35px;
    padding:20px;
}

/********NAV BAR*******/
nav
{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}

nav ul
{
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.topnav li
{
    list-style: none;
    float : left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.topnav li.topnav-right
{
    float : right;
}

ul.topnav li a
{
    display : block;
    text-decoration : none;
    min-height:16px;
    text-align:centre;
    padding:14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#665;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover
{
    background-color: #0000ff;
    color:#fff;
}

ul.topnav li.dropdownicon
{
    display: none;
}
button
{
    font-size:32px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#0069ff;
    padding: 15px 60px;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    margin:5px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

button.learnMore
{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
.container 
{
    width : 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 4%;
    padding-bottom: 4%;   
    background: 
}
/********custom style*******/
#section-1-gradient
{
    background:#076DFF;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#076DFF, #65A5FF);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#076DFF, #65A5FF);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#076DFF, #65A5FF);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#076DFF, #65A5FF);
}

div.box
{
    margin:24px;
    text-align:center;  
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 36px 24px 36px 24px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.15),
        0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

div.slopeIcon img
{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    box-shadow: -2px -2px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15),
        2px 2px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
h1.large
{
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 56px;
    margin:0;
    line-height: 70px;
}

h1.section2header
{
    font-size:65px;
    text-align:center;
}

div.leftside-col
{
    margin-left:30%;
    
}

div.rightside-col
{
    margin-left:15%;    
}
input[type="password"], /* added by shamil*/
input[type="text"]
{
    font-size: 20px;
    width:400px;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius: 7px
}



form h2
{
    color:white;
}
.row
{
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex:wrap;    
    align-items:center;    
}

.row::after
{
    display:table;
    clear: both;
    content:"";
}

.col-1{width:8.33%;}
.col-2{width:16.66%;}
.col-3{width:25%;}
.col-4{width:33.33%;}
.col-5{width:41.66%;}
.col-6{width:50%;}
.col-7{width:58.33%;}
.col-8{width:66.66%;}
.col-9{width:75%;}
.col-10{width:83.33%;}
.col-11{width:91.66%;}
.col-12{width:100%;}


*{
    box-sizing: border-box
}

footer.footsy
{
    background-color: #666; 
    padding:2%
}

footer.footsy h1
{
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 35px;
}

footer.footsy ul
{
    list-style: none;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left: 0;
}

footer.footsy ul li
{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:22px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
/********MOBILE*******/
@media screen and (max-width : 680px)
{
    ul.topnav li:not(:nth-child(1))
    {
        display: none;
    }
    ul.topnav li.dropdownicon
    {
        display:block;
        float: right;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li.dropdownicon{
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive{
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li{
        display:inline;
        float : none;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li a
    {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    h1.section2header
    {
        font-size:55px;
    }
    
    .row {
    flex-direction: column;
        
    }
    
    article p
    {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    
    .col-4,
    .col-5,
    .col-6,
    .col-7
    {
        width:100%;
        margin:0;            
    }
    
    div.mobilestack
    {
        width:50%;
        display: block;
        margin:0;
    }
    
    div.box
    {
        padding:5px;
        display:block;
    }
    div.slopeIcon
    {
        margin:10px;
    }
    div.slopeIcon img
    {
        width:100%;
    }
    
    div.rightside-col,
    div.leftside-col
    {
        width:15%;
    }
   input[type="password"],
    input[type="text"]
    {
        width:200px;
        float:left;
        padding:5px;
    }
   .videoContainer iframe
    {
       width:400px;
        float:left;
        padding:5px; ;
    }
    .footsy .row {
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>
        Anime Shop 
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">              

    </head>
    
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul class="topnav" id="dropdownClick">
                <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#News">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
                <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#Signup">Sign up</a></li>
                <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#Signin">Sign in</a></li>
                <li class="dropdownicon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick = "dropdownMenu()">&#9776</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <div class="container" id="section-1-gradient">
            <div class="row">
                <div class= "col-6">
                    <div class= "leftside-col">
                        <h1 class="large">
                        Crazy radness
                        </h1>
                        <h1 class="large">
                        Made for Otaku
                        </h1>
                        <form>
                            <div class= "leftside-col">
                                <h2>Username</h2>
                                <input class="inputbox" type="text" name="Username "placeholder="Username">
                                <h2>Password</h2>
                                <input class="inputbox" type="password" name="Password "placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class= "col-6">
                    <div class= "rightside-col">
                        <div class="videoContainer">
                            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uC_SgMzlr6U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>     
        </div>
        <header>
        <h1 class = "section2header"> Top Anime Counties </h1>  
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img src="devIcon.png">
                        </div>
                        <label>Anime</label>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
                    </div>              
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img src="devIcon.png">
                        </div>
                        <label>Manga</label>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
                    </div>              
                </div>  
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img src="devIcon.png">
                        </div>
                        <label>Anime and Manga</label>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
                    </div>              
                </div>  
                
            </div>                      
            <div class ="row">
                    <div class ="col-12">
                        <button class="learnMore">Learn More</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7">
                    <article>
                        <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                        </p>
                    </article>

                </div>
                <div class= "col-5">
                    <div class="slopeIcon">
                        <img src="iOS_Slope.png">
                    </div>          
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
         <footer class="footsy">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3 mobilestack">
                    <h1>Company</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Blogs</li>
                        <li>Careers</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 mobilestack">
                    <h1>Organization</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Blogs</li>
                        <li>Careers</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 mobilestack">
                    <h1>Industry</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Blogs</li>
                        <li>Careers</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 mobilestack">
                    <h1>Maanagement</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Blogs</li>
                        <li>Careers</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </footer> 
        <script>
            function dropdownMenu()           
            {
               var x= document.getElementById("dropdownClick");
                if(x.className === "topnav")
                {
                    x.className = "topnav responsive";
                    /*change topnav to topnav.responsive*/
                }
                else
                {
                    x.className = "topnav";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead defining width or other stuff to create a grid system for your project you can easily use formal grid system css has, like flexbox or css grid.
Here I'm showing you how to use css grid for this purpose:

```css
.area{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.footer{ display: grid; }

@media(min-width: 600px){
  .footer{
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 599px){
  .footer{
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <div class="area">
       <h3> header 1 </h3>
       <ul> 
        <li>link1</li>
        <li>link2</li>
        <li>link3</li> 
       </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="area">
       <h3> header 2 </h3>
       <ul> 
        <li>link1</li>
        <li>link2</li>
        <li>link3</li> 
       </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="area">
       <h3> header 3 </h3>
       <ul> 
        <li>link1</li>
        <li>link2</li>
        <li>link3</li> 
       </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="area">
       <h3> header 4 </h3>
       <ul> 
        <li>link1</li>
        <li>link2</li>
        <li>link3</li> 
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add  .footsy .row{display:block;}  and
div.mobilestack{width:45%; display:inline-block;margin:0;}
for disable flex direction column

```css
/********DEFAULTS*******/
        nav,header,footer
        {
            display:block;
        }

        body
        {
            line-height: 1;
            margin :0;
        }

        label
        {
            font-size: 35px;
            font-weight: 600
        }

        p
        {
            font-size:28px;
            line-height: 1.2;
        }

        article p
        {
            font-size:35px;
            padding:20px;
        }

        /********NAV BAR*******/
        nav
        {
            width:100%;
            margin:0;
        }

        nav ul
        {
            background-color: #eee;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        ul.topnav li
        {
            list-style: none;
            float : left;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        ul.topnav li.topnav-right
        {
            float : right;
        }

        ul.topnav li a
        {
            display : block;
            text-decoration : none;
            min-height:16px;
            text-align:centre;
            padding:14px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color:#665;
        }

        ul.topnav li a:hover
        {
            background-color: #0000ff;
            color:#fff;
        }

        ul.topnav li.dropdownicon
        {
            display: none;
        }
        button
        {
            font-size:32px;
            font-weight: 700;
            color:#fff;
            background-color:#0069ff;
            padding: 15px 60px;
            display:block;
            text-align: center;
            margin:5px;
            border-radius: 7px;
        }

        button.learnMore
        {
            display:block;
            margin:auto;
        }
        .container 
        {
            width : 100%;
            margin: auto;
            padding-top: 4%;
            padding-bottom: 4%;   
            background: 
        }
        /********custom style*******/
        #section-1-gradient
        {
            background:#076DFF;
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#076DFF, #65A5FF);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#076DFF, #65A5FF);
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#076DFF, #65A5FF);
            background-image: linear-gradient(#076DFF, #65A5FF);
        }

        div.box
        {
            margin:24px;
            text-align:center;  
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 36px 24px 36px 24px;
            border-radius: 7px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.15),
                0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        }

        div.slopeIcon img
        {
            display:block;
            margin:auto;
            box-shadow: -2px -2px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15),
                2px 2px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
        }
        h1.large
        {
            color:#fff;
            font-size: 56px;
            margin:0;
            line-height: 70px;
        }

        h1.section2header
        {
            font-size:65px;
            text-align:center;
        }

        div.leftside-col
        {
            margin-left:30%;
            
        }

        div.rightside-col
        {
            margin-left:15%;    
        }
        input[type="password"], /* added by shamil*/
        input[type="text"]
        {
            font-size: 20px;
            width:400px;
            min-width: 100px;
            padding:5px;
            border-radius: 7px
        }



        form h2
        {
            color:white;
        }
        .row
        {
            width:100%;
            display:flex;
            flex:wrap;    
            align-items:center;    
        }

        .row::after
        {
            display:table;
            clear: both;
            content:"";
        }

        .col-1{width:8.33%;}
        .col-2{width:16.66%;}
        .col-3{width:25%;}
        .col-4{width:33.33%;}
        .col-5{width:41.66%;}
        .col-6{width:50%;}
        .col-7{width:58.33%;}
        .col-8{width:66.66%;}
        .col-9{width:75%;}
        .col-10{width:83.33%;}
        .col-11{width:91.66%;}
        .col-12{width:100%;}


        *{
            box-sizing: border-box
        }

        footer.footsy
        {
            background-color: #666; 
            padding:2%
        }

        footer.footsy h1
        {
            color:#fff;
            font-size: 35px;
        }

        footer.footsy ul
        {
            list-style: none;
            text-align:left;
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        footer.footsy ul li
        {
            color:#fff;
            font-size:22px;
            line-height: 1.5;
        }
        /********MOBILE*******/
        @media screen and (max-width : 680px)
        {
            ul.topnav li:not(:nth-child(1))
            {
                display: none;
            }
            ul.topnav li.dropdownicon
            {
                display:block;
                float: right;
            }
            ul.topnav.responsive li.dropdownicon{
                position: absolute;
                top:0;
                right:0;
            }
            ul.topnav.responsive{
                position: relative;
            }
            ul.topnav.responsive li{
                display:inline;
                float : none;
            }
            ul.topnav.responsive li a
            {
                display: block;
                text-align: left;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            
            h1.section2header
            {
                font-size:55px;
            }
            
            .row {
            flex-direction: column;
                
            }
            .footsy .row{
              display:block;
            }
            
            article p
            {
                font-size: 25px;
            }
            
            .col-4,
            .col-5,
            .col-6,
            .col-7
            {
                width:100%;
                margin:0;            
            }
            
            div.mobilestack
            {
                width:45%;
                display:inline-block;
                margin:0;
            }
            
            div.box
            {
                padding:5px;
                display:block;
            }
            div.slopeIcon
            {
                margin:10px;
            }
            div.slopeIcon img
            {
                width:100%;
            }
            
            div.rightside-col,
            div.leftside-col
            {
                width:15%;
            }
           input[type="password"],
            input[type="text"]
            {
                width:200px;
                float:left;
                padding:5px;
            }
           .videoContainer iframe
            {
               width:400px;
                float:left;
                padding:5px; ;
            }
        }
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>
        Anime Shop 
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">              

    </head>
    
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul class="topnav" id="dropdownClick">
                <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#News">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
                <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#Signup">Sign up</a></li>
                <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#Signin">Sign in</a></li>
                <li class="dropdownicon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick = "dropdownMenu()">&#9776</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <div class="container" id="section-1-gradient">
            <div class="row">
                <div class= "col-6">
                    <div class= "leftside-col">
                        <h1 class="large">
                        Crazy radness
                        </h1>
                        <h1 class="large">
                        Made for Otaku
                        </h1>
                        <form>
                            <div class= "leftside-col">
                                <h2>Username</h2>
                                <input class="inputbox" type="text" name="Username "placeholder="Username">
                                <h2>Password</h2>
                                <input class="inputbox" type="password" name="Password "placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class= "col-6">
                    <div class= "rightside-col">
                        <div class="videoContainer">
                            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uC_SgMzlr6U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>     
        </div>
        <header>
        <h1 class = "section2header"> Top Anime Counties </h1>  
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img src="devIcon.png">
                        </div>
                        <label>Anime</label>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
                    </div>              
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img src="devIcon.png">
                        </div>
                        <label>Manga</label>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
                    </div>              
                </div>  
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img src="devIcon.png">
                        </div>
                        <label>Anime and Manga</label>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
                    </div>              
                </div>  
                
            </div>                      
            <div class ="row">
                    <div class ="col-12">
                        <button class="learnMore">Learn More</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7">
                    <article>
                        <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                        </p>
                    </article>

                </div>
                <div class= "col-5">
                    <div class="slopeIcon">
                        <img src="iOS_Slope.png">
                    </div>          
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
         <footer class="footsy">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3 mobilestack">
                    <h1>Company</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Blogs</li>
                        <li>Careers</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 mobilestack">
                    <h1>Organization</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Blogs</li>
                        <li>Careers</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 mobilestack">
                    <h1>Industry</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Blogs</li>
                        <li>Careers</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 mobilestack">
                    <h1>Maanagement</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Blogs</li>
                        <li>Careers</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </footer> 
        <script>
            function dropdownMenu()           
            {
               var x= document.getElementById("dropdownClick");
                if(x.className === "topnav")
                {
                    x.className = "topnav responsive";
                    /*change topnav to topnav.responsive*/
                }
                else
                {
                    x.className = "topnav";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```